# Whats the difference between InplaceStringBuilder and StringBuilder?

Tags: memory-management, asp.net-core, .net-core, stringbuilder

Today in VS2017 intellisense surfaced `InplaceStringBuilder` when I was trying to type `StringBuilder`.  `InplaceStringBuilder` is new to me so I started digging to see what I could learn.

The first thing I noticed is that it's a struct and not a class and it's type information looks like this:

```
#region Assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
// C:\Users\Ron Clabo\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\wwwGiftOasisResponsive\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.1.1.0\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll
#endregion

using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives {
    [DebuggerDisplay("Value = {_value}")]
    public struct InplaceStringBuilder {
        public InplaceStringBuilder(int capacity);

        public int Capacity { get; set; }

        public void Append(string s);
        public void Append(char c);
        public override string ToString();
    }
}
```

So it has alot fewer methods than `StringBuilder`.  Then I googled around to learn more about `InplaceStringBuilder` but there's not much on the web about it yet, so it looks to be pretty new.

Besides, the differences I have already mentioned, what are the differences between `InplaceStringBuilder` and `StringBuilder`; and when should a developer use the new `InplaceStringBuilder` instead of the age old `StringBuilder`?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be much info out there on it, other than *Intended to be used instead of pooled StringBuilder or string.Concat when all parts of string are known.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal `StringBuilder` increases the capacity when the resulting string is longer than the initial capacity. The `InplaceStringBuilder` is limited to its capacity and throws an exception if the resulting string is longer.

This is quite a limitation of `InplaceStringBuilder`, so it may only be suitable in rare cases. In addition, if you know the capacity in advance, it was already possible to define the initial capacity of a normal `StringBuilder`.

Source: look at the implementation of `InplaceStringBuilder` on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Common/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives/InplaceStringBuilder.cs) and compare to `StringBuilder` on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You have a source for this?

Comment: That's just a link to the source code, I meant, do you have a link to some docs or somewhere that an official person reiterates what you said.

Comment: Super interesting.  Agreed it was already possible to define the initial capacity of a normal StringBuilder which would eliminate the need for multiple allocations.

Comment: @ThomasWeller no worries, I kept typing a different wrong variant of the name when writing up the question. It's gonna take a bit for `InplaceStringBuilder` to stick in our heads. In fact, after looking at the source code a better name might have been InplaceStringManipulator :-)

Answer (score 5):

Since it only does one allocation, `InplaceStringBuilder` is more efficient for well-known, reasonably-sized strings. We might want to use it in methods that need to be very efficient.

It was introduced with [pull request #157](https://github.com/aspnet/Common/pull/157), which includes the following commentary.

> Intended to be used instead of pooled `StringBuilder` or `string.Concat` when all parts of string are known... Does only 1 allocation of resulting string... should only be used for well-known reasonably sized strings. For everything else, use `StringBuilder`...  do not use across await points...

The history of the PR tells the story:

1. July 2016, [Issue #676](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/issues/676) notices unnecessary allocations.
2. Sept 2016, [Pull request #699](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/pull/699) resolves issue #676 and proposes factoring out the "inplace string formatting into a struct..."
3. Sept 2016, [Issue #717](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/pull/717) formalizes the proposal.
4. Sept 2016, [Pull request #157](https://github.com/aspnet/Common/pull/157) implements the proposal.

Answer (score 3):

`InplaceStringBuilder` is a very fast way to build a string by appending chunks, when you know in advance how long the final string is going to be. It works by preallocating a `string` of fixed size, and then *mutating* that string (unsafely, through a pointer) as you append chunks to the builder. When you call `ToString`, the preallocated string, now full of data, is returned directly without copying. (`StringBuilder` makes a copy of its content when you call `ToString`.)

Strings are ordinarily immutable, so you'd better make sure not to mutate the string by calling `Append` after you've called `ToString`. `InplaceStringBuilder` tries to make this safe by only allowing appends (you can't rewind and write to a part of the string which has already been appended) and by requiring you to fill the entire string before calling `ToString`.

However, `InplaceStringBuilder` is a mutable struct, which means it's passed around by copying. If you copy the builder (eg by passing it as an argument), the copy can get out of sync with the original. Specifically, the `_offset` field, which tracks how many characters have been appended so far (in order to know where to write the next `Append` call), of the copy may refer to a location in the string which has already been written by the original.

This is to say, `InplaceStringBuilder` is **unsafe** and risky to use. If not handled carefully, you risk breaking one of `string`'s most important properties, immutability. Make sure you know what you're doing!